# How do you write to a blocking device file using Java?

Tags: java, linux, io

I have a character special device file on a Linux system (eg /dev/foobardcma6) that I wish to constantly write data to. What is the preferred way to do this in Java?

I tried using `AsynchronousFileChannel` and was able to write some bytes to it, but eventually it blocks/hangs when writing. I don't know if this is the right approach or not, however.

I could use a `FileChannel`. The write method returns how many bytes were actually written. I assume if it returns less bytes than were requested to write, it means the write buffer is full, and you should wait before writing again. However, I don't see any mechanism to be notified that the file is ready for writing.

**Update:**

I tried using a `FileChannel`, and it also blocks after a certain number of bytes. The suspicious thing is both the `FileChannel` and `AsychronousFileChannel` implementations block after writing *exactly* the same number of bytes. In both cases the last call to `write` never returns.

I have a test utility written in C++ that can successfully write data to the device without issue, so it's not a hardware problem. I assume I'm doing something wrong with the FileChannels.

Comment: What is "blocking device"? Do you mean block device?

Comment: @dimich sorry, I was mixing terms. It's a "character special device file". The problem is that it is blocking. I edited the question

Comment: If `write()` call blocks it means driver [temporary] won't accept data for some reason. It is specific to the driver which handles the device, you can do nothing with it from userspace. You should access device file like any other blocking IO. If the driver supports `poll()` you can wait with `POLLOUT` on file descriptor. Or set `O_NONBLOCK` flag and access device in nonblocking mode. Or call blocking operations in a separate thread.